# I have dual booted Ubuntu but have very little space

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, 20.04, gparted

I have dual-booted Ubuntu 20.04, but have very little space and can't understand why. Granted, I'm a bit of a noob.

If I run `gparted`, I see the following:
[image]

But then, if I run `disk usage analyser`, I see

[image]

So, I think I've lively done something wrong during installation. Can anyone advise how I could sort out the installation so that I can access the several GB of memory the laptop has available?

Comment: Looks like you forgot to *mount* your /home partition. That's why the /home space isn't available. Perhaps a mistake following whatever instructions you used. Revisit those instructions, particularly about editing /etc/fstab so the partition will mount automatically. FYI: A /home partition is optional (it does not behave like a D: drive).

Comment: Thier home partition is mounted or they wouldn't have been able to login.  The problem is their `/` partition is just very small.

Comment: Thank you for your responses. I followed the instructions [here](https://community.acer.com/en/discussion/549078/how-compatible-is-ubuntu-with-predator-helios-300-series). Do you know if there's anything I can do now to increase the size of the partition?

Comment: Delete existing swap partition p6, enlarge root partition p5 to use the free space. This gives you 33 GB of free space in p5. You can add a small swap file again in p5 afterwards. 4 GB should be more than enough.
You need to to all this from a live usb, though.

Comment: Many thanks for your help here. OK, so I should boot from a USB which has an Ubuntu image, and from here, resize partitions using `gparted`? Does it have to be the same USB which which I originally installed Ubuntu? Because I installed Ubuntu 18.04 from a USB drive, and then upgraded to 20.04

Comment: @ignoring_gravity: No, you can use any live USB Ubuntu with gparted on.

Comment: Oh wow, looks like this worked! Thank you so much all for your help, I really appreciate it!!!